# Error: Expecting a single value: [extent = 10]

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to create multiple dataframes with a function in R.  I found something here that helped me build the framework of the function, but I am getting the "Error: Expecting a single value: [extent = 10]" issue.

I have data that I am filtering and grouping, which works fine on its own if I am creating a dataframe of using a single value for (x).  When I try to run using a vector of dates, I get the error.

See code below, hope it makes sense:

```
target<-#vector of dates as a character class

test<-function(x) {
    listofevents<-list()

    for (i in 1:length(x)){
      results<-mainDF %>% filter(between(Date, x - 30, x)) %>% 
      group_by(Name) %>% summarise(Total_Wins = sum(TotalW),Total_Records = n())
      listofevents[[i]]<-results
    }

    return(listofevents)
  }

  test(x=lubridate::mdy(target))
```

Comment: It would help if you provide a small sample of `target` that reproduces your error.

Comment: That seems to be the error you get when you pass a vector to the `left` or `right` arguments of `dplyr::between`. The documentation doesn't say explicitly, but it seem to indicate that between is vectorized for `x`, but not for `left` or `right` (e.g., the examples show `x` with length > 1, but single values for `left` and `right`). I would recommend just switching to `filter(x - 30 <= Date & Date <= x)`

Comment: If you're married to the `between` syntax, you could switch to `data.table::between` which works this way.

Comment: Thanks Gregor.  This is VERY close.  It gives me the output but it repeats the results 10 times instead of giving results for each of the 10 different dates in (x).  I also get 20 warnings that say "In `<=.default`(Date, x) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length